# Double line in Canvas DBSignatureView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, signature

I'm implementing a digital signature in my application using Objective c, but when I tap the screen and drag the finger, the line is cut in two.

This is the code:

```
UIScrollView *contenido = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
contenido.bounces = NO;

DBSignatureView *vistaFirma = [[DBSignatureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, (margen-5) , tamCelda=tamCanvas)];
    [
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]vistaFirma addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    vistaFirma.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    vistaFirma.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    vistaFirma.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    [contenido insertSubview:vistaFirma atIndex:contenido.subviews.count-(contenido.subviews.count > 1 ? 1 : 0)];
```

[image]

Which property should I implement?